# How can I determine the meaning of an odd entry in tracert output?

Tags: networking, traceroute

My router / gateway is on 10.0.0.1, with it handing out DHCP addresses in the range of 10.0.0.10 - 50.

I did a tracert on yahoo today and noticed something odd, the 10.196.192.1 entry in the list below.  I know that that's a private IP, but I don't have any devices that would correspond to that at all.  Any idea what that is?

```
Tracing route to yahoo.com [98.139.183.24]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  ir2.fp.vip.bf1.yahoo.com [98.139.183.24]
  2   211 ms   201 ms   202 ms  10.196.192.1
  3   181 ms   186 ms   188 ms  dynamic-76-73-171-181.knology.net [76.73.171.181]
  4   207 ms   216 ms   222 ms  pat2.nyc.yahoo.com [198.32.118.224]
  5   260 ms   206 ms   220 ms  ae-2.pat2.bfz.yahoo.com [216.115.100.74]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly normal. It just means that your path goes through some internal architecure that is using private addresses.

There is an answer on ServerFault about this:

[Traceroute includes un-routable IP (?)](https://serverfault.com/questions/59516/traceroute-includes-un-routable-ip)